# Input type file is not working on Chrome?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, input, safari, input-type-file

I am building a fullStack project with react where you can create posts.
I am trying to use input type file to upload a picture, but when I click the choose file button, the pop up window does not appear. Here is the input:

```
<input type="file" onChange={e => setPhoto(e.currentTarget.files[0])} />
```

This isn't working. I tried changing onChange for onInput and it is still not working. I also looked around to make sure it wasn't nested inside another element that had e.stopPropagation or e.preventDefault. It is not. I tried placing it in different parts of my code and components and it still isn't working.

Something that I found curious is that, this issue is happening on Chrome. When I checked my localhost on Safari, the window where I can select the file pops up.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: It sometimes happens on macos. Try to update chrome or restart the system.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski there were no errors. You were right. I had to update Chrome. Thank you so much.

Comment: This happened to me just today. Updating chrome manually fixed it